# Reference question: Adjunction between non-negative and unbounded chain complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring. It seems obvious that the inclusion $Ch(R)^+\hookrightarrow Ch(R)$ of non-negatively graded chain complexes into the category of unbounded  chain complexes admits a right-adjoint, which is usually called the good truncation, and which to a chain complex
$$\ldots \xleftarrow{d_{0}}M_0\xleftarrow{d_{1}}M_1\xleftarrow{d_{2}}\ldots$$
associates the non-negatively graded complex
$$Ker(d_0)\xleftarrow{d_{1}}M_1\xleftarrow{d_{2}}\ldots.$$

However, I can not find a reference to cite. Can someone help please?

Comment: Do you really need one? I think you can just state this, verifying the universal property is straightforward.

Comment: I agree, it is completely obvious. This is why I though someone must have mentioned it, but whatever, no-one will complain about this I guess...